# How to determine with what values is a div overflowing in all the directions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to know if there is any way by which I can determine with what quantities a div is overflowing in any direction. Searches in the internet only took me to the point where I can figure out the total horizontal or vertical values with which a div is overflowing. But, I wanted to know the exact `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and compute value on [DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect) value.

This API has a good [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=getBoundingClientRect).

Inside a `Reactjs` component you should use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for access to div at phisycal DOM.

```js
import React from 'react';

const Foobar = () => {

  const onRef = (element) => {

    const domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    console.log(`
        quantity before overflow top: ${domRect.y}px
        quantity before overflow left: ${domRect.x}px
        quantity before overflow right: ${window.screen.width - domRect.right}px
        quantity before overflow bottom: ${window.screen.height - domRect.bottom}px
    `);
  };
  
  return (
    <div ref={onRef}>
      {# ... #}
    </div>
  );

}

export default Foobar;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and post the updates